# Change php function on select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a problem with some javascript and php code. I want to tried a few things with some ajax calls which did not work.

What i want to happen:
When i change the selected option it need to update the function with the value from the option, so the php function get the "id" from the selected option. And this need to happen without any refresh on the page.

So i need to get the value from the selected item to the php function.

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function ()
{
    $('#select').change(function()
    {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $('#showoption').val(option); // for testing

        $.ajax ({
            url: "scripts/script.php",
            data: { id : option },
            success: {}
        });

    });
});
</script>
                <?php
                $meals = $food->mealsByCategory($id);
                foreach($meals as $meal){
                ?>
                    <div class="entry style-columns">
                        <div class="entry-title">
                            <a href="#"><?php echo $meal->DanName; ?></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

The .change() works now, but it still is not passing to the php function where i need $id. In the scripts/script.php file i have `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Yeah i know, but how?

Comment: *"I want to tried a few things with some ajax calls which did not work."* - Show us what you tried. There's no Ajax/JS here.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, i can not show you anything, because i deleted it..

Comment: you need js `onchange` to detect the `option` changes and then you need ajax/post to send the values to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duuude, if your using jquery its easy like this…

if your html look like this:

```
<div class="form-label">Category</div>
<select name="category">
<option value="abcde">abcde-text</option>
<option value="fghij">fghij-text</option>
</select>
<div class="loaded"></div>
```

your ajax must look like this simple as it goes…

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //DOM LOADED
    $( "select" ).change(function () { //GET CHANGE CALL
    var str = ""; // CREATE AN EMPTY STRING
    str += $(this).val(); // GET ACTUALL VALUE
    $( ".loaded" ).text( str ); // PRINT STRING WHEREVER YOU WANT
  })
  .change();
});
```

or load a file instead of print the text …

```
$.ajax({ url: '/ajax.php', // WHICH FILE YOU WANN CALL IN MY EX THIS WOULD BE str+'.php',
         data: formData, //
         type: 'post', // GET or POST 
         complete: function(output) {
               $('/*FORM RESULT*/').html(output.responseText);
         }
});
```

hope this help you out…

Comment: Thanks, can you please look at my updated post, i need it to pass to the php function..

Comment: is it important to post otherwise try via get to hold it simple '/ajax.php?meal='+str and in the php $mealid = htmlspecialchars(is_numeric($_GET['meal']));

if($mealid) { /* call your function */ }

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
$.get('url-with-get').done(function(data) { $("selector").after(data); });
```

Also, you should put that inside something like this

```
$('#your-list-id').on('change', function() {});
```

you can change after for whatever, data is what you get from the ajax call, so in your php file it should have something like

```
if(isset($_GET['var-you-are-passing-in-url-with-get'])){
echo 'bla bla bla';
}
```

hope this helps :)